# serial upvote rules

Tags: discussion

What are the rules that detects the serial upvotes

one time I got a serial upvote reversed but I wonder what is the algorithm that detects this. I know it is related to users upvoting to each others.

But what triggers it, what's the acceptable range of upvotes.

Comment: That's something that only the SE developers know. So no one can game the system.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way the serial voting works on SE sites is documented here:

- [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

Answer (score 0):

Not even the NSA knows, you expect us to know?

Comment: wow, I am shocked